# activity in manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, rotation, orientation

i have one activity in my manifest.xml my activity is CPohonApp but in this activity i have 2 config

this is my manifest

```
<activity android:name=".pupuk.CPupukApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

and

```
<activity android:name=".pupuk.CPupukApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

when run this code is not work.

how to run two config in one name activity in manifest.xml?

thank you.

sorry for my bad english

Alex

Comment: how the code if i put code sub activity in CPupukApp in android name in manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex when you set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` then your activity remains in portrait mode so **no need to declare** `orientation` configChanges. Try this.

**If you have more than one configuration for particular activity then no need to declare it more than one time . Declare all those in that single activity.**

```
<activity android:name=".pupuk.CPupukApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```

Comment: how the code if i put code sub activity in CPupukApp in android name in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

add the two configurations to single activity initialization

```
<activity android:name=".pupuk.CPupukApp" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
```